# Is it possible to fetch data from an RSS Feed without an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, rss

I have to fetch data from a RSS feed but the problem is that there is no Access-Control-Allow-Origin header to permit us to read data.

I have tried:

```
        function createCORSRequest(method, url){
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        // if ("withCredentials" in xhr){
        if (xhr.withCredentials == true){
            xhr.open(method, url, true);
        } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined"){
            xhr = new XDomainRequest();
            xhr.open(method, url);
        } else {
            xhr = null;
        }
        return xhr;
    }

    function fetchData() {
        var request = createCORSRequest("get", "http://example.com/data");
        if (request){
            // request.onload = function() {
            //     console.log(request);
            // };
            request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                    console.log(request.responseText);
                }
            };
            request.send();
        }
    }
```

But it still has this error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

I have also tried Ajax but still not working. Is there any other way?

*Please note that we are **not allowed to use jQuery** or any other plug-ins and framework. It has to be written only in JavaScript. Please don't ask why as it is a topic that even I can't answer.*

Comment: Nope.  The browser prevents you from doing that for a very good reason. You can always create your own proxy server however, so that your browser would make an HTTP request to the proxy, which would fetch content from the remote site and return it. But you cannot do it just from the browser unless you control the target site and can reconfigure the headers.

Comment: I edited the website name in the code to "example.com", which is already designed as a domain name for examples.

Comment: @Pointy I see, so we have to contact the admin of the site then? I don't know about using proxies if they're going to allow us but what if I use ajax, will it still be possible?

Comment: @PeterO.Thanks peter, I'll remember that :D

Comment: Well I don't know who "they" are here, but it's a simple fact that browsers quite deliberately prevent code loaded from site A to make XHR requests to site B unless site B says it's OK.

Comment: @Pointy Oh sorry lol, What I meant with 'they' is the client who asked for the work :) *sigh* this is so hard.. :/

Comment: Ha ha no, it's fine; I was just saying that regardless of what anybody wants, browsers simply won't do it. Making a proxy is not a big deal really; it can be done in just about any server-side framework/language.